# How can I download flash games?

Tags: download, flash, swf

I would like to download the flash game [here](http://downloads.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/ks2/games/questionaut/quest.swf). I have tried just saving that flash file like most other tutorials recommend, however when I open it(in Chrome) it lets me press "Play" however it then goes blank except for the speaker icon. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks,

Tugzrida

Comment: Thanks @Psycogeek Your comment led me to using Adobe Flash CC to open the original SWF file. In the log, the missing files URL's were displayed so I played the whole game through, downloading the missing files as I went. I know that's tedious and there's probably an easier way but it worked for me. If you write an answer then I can mark it as the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern flash games can be more parts and pieces, than back when simple flash game making started, you could clear your net temps fully, then refresh the page, and attempt to see what it is made up of (could be more things needed).

Modern flash can also have links that tie it to a web site, sometimes added on purpose to keep it on the sites.

Try with other simple games, and from other sites till you see how a simple single .swf item one would work, then go from there.